# Save button doesn't work

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub ItemsBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ItemsBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
        Me.Validate()
        Me.ItemsBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.LolokikoDataSet)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'LolokikoDataSet.Items' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.ItemsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.LolokikoDataSet.Items)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ItemsBindingNavigatorSaveItem.PerformClick()
        MsgBox("updated")

    End Sub
End Class
```

I'm just following a YouTube tutorial on `DataGrid` and my save button doesn't work.

Comment: Is ItemsBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click firing?

Comment: no i tried that and got an error "argument not specified for parameter 'sender' of 'Private Sub ItemBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(Sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)'

Comment: How about ItemsBindingNavigatorSaveItem.PerformClick(this)? Or the VB equivalent, I don't remember.

Comment: Which of the two buttons in the above code are you referring to when you say "my save button".

Comment: @KevenDenen im referring to Button1_Click